# Sum on subqueries on SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a query with some subqueries inside and I want to add a sum query to sum them all.
How can I do that?

example:

```
Id,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 on ...) as col1,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table3 LEFT JOIN table4 on ...) as col2,
** Sum of both col1 and col2 here **
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT ID, col1, col2, [Total] = (col1 + col2)
FROM (
    SELECT Id,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 on ...) as col1,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table3 LEFT JOIN table4 on ...) as col2
    FROM [TABLE]) T
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

the easiest way would be to treat all your query as a subquery

```
select Id, col1 + col2 as total
from
(<yourCode>) s
```

Because it's not possible to use alias in the same "level of query" in the select clause.