# How do I combine SQL SUM from multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to get the sum from multiple tables. Here's the structure:

H1 table

```
 DocID
 DocNum
 DocDate
```

D1 table

```
 DocID
 ItemNum
 Quantity
```

H2 table

```
 DocID
 DocNum
 DocDate
```

D2 table

```
 DocID
 ItemNum
 Quantity
```

The sum I need is the total Quantity from D1 and D2 tables for an Item. My query code below did not work:

```
SELECT SUM(Qty) 
FROM
    (SELECT SUM(D1.Quantity) AS Qty 
     FROM D1 
     INNER JOIN H1 ON H1.DocNum = D1.DocNum 
     WHERE D1.Item = 'watch' AND H1.DocDate = '2020-09-30'

     UNION 

     SELECT SUM(D2.Quantity) AS Qty 
     FROM D2 
     INNER JOIN H2 ON H2.DocNum = D2.DocNum 
     WHERE D2.Item = 'watch' AND H2.DocDate = '2020-09-30')
```

I've edited to display (dummy) data and the expected output to show what I mean

```
[H1] table
DocID DocNum DocDate
1     1001   2020-09-30
2     1002   2020-09-30
[D1] table
DocID ItemNum Quantity
1     10      100
2     10      150

[H2] table
DocID DocNum DocDate
11    2011   2020-09-30
12    2012   2020-09-30
[D2] table
DocID ItemNum Quantity
11    10      50
12    10      200
```

The expected output:

```
ItemNum  Quantity
10       500
```

Comment: Are you missing a `UNION` between the two inner `SELECT` statements?

Comment: I added a UNION between the two inner SQL. The code is updated). Still not getting the sum

Comment: Use UNION ALL instead of UNION. Plain UNION removes duplicates and you want to count all values.

Comment: Make all our lives easy, show some sample data and expected results - then its really clear what you are trying to accomplish. Even better, show your sample data as DDL+DML and we can copy and paste to test.

Comment: I've showed sample data and the expected output

Comment: What does "did not work" mean?

Answer (score 0):

How about adding UNION

--- EDIT ---
Trying another approach
--- EDIT ---

```
SELECT [Qty] = (d1 + d2)
FROM (
    (SELECT SUM(D1.Quantity) AS Qty 
     FROM D1 
     INNER JOIN H1 ON H1.DocNum = D1.DocNum 
     WHERE D1.Item = 'watch' AND H1.DocDate = '2020-09-30') as d1,
   (SELECT SUM(D2.Quantity) AS Qty 
   FROM D2 
   INNER JOIN H2 ON H2.DocNum = D2.DocNum 
   WHERE D2.Item = 'watch' AND H2.DocDate = '2020-09-30') as d2
);
```

Comment: If I run the inner selects, I get the sums. But if I run all together I' get incorrect syntax near  ')' -on the last line. I also get an invalid column nae on the outer SELECT SUM(Qty)

Comment: Do you get two lines if you run query without outer sum. Two queries together with union all. And probably you wouldn't need summing on inner queries. Outer sum does it anyway.

Comment: yes I got the two lines without the outer sum. I also tried the Union All and removing the sum on the inner queries. Still not getting the sums from the tables

Comment: And you are using Microsoft SQL server?

Comment: I don't have MSSQL server on hand, but I edided query. Found that approach from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21195582/sum-on-subqueries-on-sql-server/21195649

Comment: @ex4 . . . In most people's opinions, commas in the `FROM` clause are never a "better" approach.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, yes I agree. That isn't pretty option. But I think Jaime already tried your approach and it didn't work for him. I had exactly the same query in my initial answer. See first comment in this answer.

Comment: @ex4 the link worked. I was able to get the results. Much obliged

Answer (score 0):

Your query has at least two obvious issues:

- There is no alias on the subquery.
- You are using `UNION` instead of `UNION ALL`.

I would recommend:

```
SELECT SUM(Qty) 
FROM ((SELECT SUM(D1.Quantity) AS Qty 
       FROM D1 JOIN
            H1
            ON H1.DocNum = D1.DocNum 
       WHERE D1.Item = 'watch' AND H1.DocDate = '2020-09-30'
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT SUM(D2.Quantity) AS Qty 
       FROM D2 JOIN
            H2
            ON H2.DocNum = D2.DocNum 
       WHERE D2.Item = 'watch' AND H2.DocDate = '2020-09-30'
      )
     ) DH;
```